# One out of two Team Projects not shown in Source Control Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, administration

I'm trying to understand how to use TFS/TSA but it's a complete mess. I can't find any complete guides or better explanations than what Microsoft is offering (And I can't understand them).

Why am I unable to see all my projects even when I am the owner of them?[image: This is how it looks at my TSA]

And at my Source Controller Explorer all I see is this.
[image]

And what is "Hosted Service Provider" and "Local Git Repositories".

Please explain this to me like I am five years old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The team projects that you can't see in Source Control Explorer should use **Git** version control. You can only use Source Control Explorer to browse and work with your codebase under **TFVC**(Team Foundation version control).

TFS/VSTS supports two types of version control **Git** and **Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC)**. Git is a **distributed** version control system, and Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) is a **centralized** version control system. Git is the default version control provider for new projects. You should use Git for version control in your projects unless you have a specific need for centralized version control features in TFVC. More details you can refer to https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/comparison-git-tfvc.

[Get Started with Git and Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/gitquickstart)

[Use Team Foundation Version Control](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/overview)